# What are the good or most efficient algorithm used in collaborative filtering?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, collaborative-filtering

I'm currently working on a recommendation system that uses collaborative filtering. And now I'm researching for a good/efficient algorithm that is geared towards movie recommendation. I'm confused because there are many algorithm like the Pearson Correlation Coefficient. And so I don't know what to use/implement.

Can you give me a good/efficient algorithm? or a site that gives a good example or simulation to the algorithm?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Give this paper about the netflix prize a read [Netflix Prize](http://www2.research.att.com/~volinsky/papers/chance.pdf). Usually the 'state of the art' is some variant of matrix factorisation such as [OrdRec](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2043956). Check out the Funk Blog [FunkSVD](http://sifter.org/~simon/journal/20061211.html) which will give you a nice simple explanation about implementing the starts of a matrix factorization technique for CF.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix factorisation ([An example in Python](http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/)) is a good starting point. Furthermore, I'd recommend [Ed Chen's Blog](http://blog.echen.me/2011/10/24/winning-the-netflix-prize-a-summary/) and [The Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html) as good introductions to the variety of methods used to solve this type of problem. The interesting thing for me having worked with this type of data is the amount of sparseness, there are of course practical limits, papers by [Emmanual Candes](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~candes/) seem to shed light on this area, excellent advanced work.